# C Segmentation fault: fscanf in a function

Tags: c, function, matrix, malloc, scanf

I'm reading a .pgm file with dimensions 512*681.

My debugger is pointing the segmentation fault to the `fscanf(image, "%d", (*M)[i][j]);`. How should I fix it?

I didn't add some functions such as `open_pgm` because I'm sure everything is OK with them.

**Input**

> 12
>   13
>   12
>   12
>   12
>   12
>   10
>   ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>


void Store(int ***M, int lines, int columns, FILE *image)
{
    for(int l = 0; l < lines; l++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < columns; c++)
        {
            fscanf(image, "%d", (*M)[l][c]);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *image;
    char *string;
    int lines;
    int columns;


    string = malloc(18*sizeof(char));

    open_pgm(string, argv, &image); 

    fscanf(image, "%d %d", &lines, &columns);

    int **M; 
    allocMatrix(&M, lines, columns);


    Store(&M, lines, columns, image);
    printf("%d\n", M_lida[0][0]);



    close(&imagem);
    close(&texto);  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assuming `M` is properly allocated, you should use `fscanf(image, "%d", &((*M)[l][c]));`

Comment: Save time, enable all compiler warning which should have warned about `fscanf(image, "%d", (*M)[l][c]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for

```
        fscanf(image, "%d", (*M)[l][c]);
```

try instead

```
        fscanf(image, "%d", &((*M)[l][c]));
```